# is it ok to use window.scrollTo() in ReactJS production website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use those functions to navigate from footer to header and vice versa.

Is it fine to take this approach, if I need to avoid the usage of refs?

```
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        window.scrollTo({top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth"});
    }
```

AND

```
    const scrollToTop = () => {
        window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there's no problem in using the window object (therefore no problem in using scrollTo). It is only important to keep in mind if your website is going to be pre-rendered by a rendertron or something similar (for SEO purposes), because the rendertron might not have a window object in it's rendering environment.

If the app is pre-rendered I might just fall back:

```
if(window !== undefined && window !== null){
    window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```